# Jmeter dynamic random variable

Tags: java, jmeter

Is it possible to limit maximum value with `${varible}` in the Random variable?
Or limit the maximum value in Random variable with other variable?

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to write a BSH post-processor to give a dynamic value for Maximum Value.

[This link](http://blog.goyello.com/2009/09/15/how-to-randomize-website-test-using-jmeter/) has an example.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and [`__Random`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function helped me.
I've used it as a value for a HTTTP request that way:

> ${__Random(min,${variable})}

So I have random value with variable maximum for each thread.

[Here is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7shxD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use the evaluate function within the Random function?

```
${__Random(min, ${__eval(${MAX})}
```